# jsonschema and date type

Tags: java, json, pojo, jsonschema

I'm just getting started with jsonschema and an example under
"Using jsonschema2pojo within your Java project (embedded)"
in
https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Getting-Started

having in mind data types of jsonschema listed here 
https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/type-format?hl=en

my schema object can be described as

```
{    
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "description": "Document",
    "type": "object",

    "properties": {
        "displayDate": { "type": "date" },
        "displayName": { "type": "string" }
    }
}
```

unfortunately a generated Pojo object will be

```
package com.example;

public interface Document {

   java.lang.Object getDisplayDate();

   void setDisplayDate(java.lang.Object arg0);

   java.lang.String getDisplayName();

   void setDisplayName(java.lang.String arg0);

}
```

has a member "displayDate" of a type Object instead of expected Date. Why?

Comment: i feel that it should be date.

Comment: yeah, but why does the Object come out?

Comment: What if you use `"type": "object", "javaType": "java.util.Date` instead of `"type": "date"`?

Comment: it results in:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: japa/parser/ParseException
 at org.jsonschema2pojo.rules.ObjectRule.createClass(ObjectRule.java:235)
 at org.jsonschema2pojo.rules.ObjectRule.apply(ObjectRule.java:99)
 at org.jsonschema2pojo.rules.ObjectRule.apply(ObjectRule.java:66)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`date` is not a valid value for `type`.  `displayDate` should be defined as

```
{ "type": "string", "format": "date" }
```

I don't know if jsonschema2pojo will convert that to a Date object like you want, but it seems that it is defaulting to Object instead of throwing an error when it encounters the invalid value for `type`.

Comment: yeah, it's a step forward, because replacing
"displayDate": { "type": "date" },
with
"displayDate": { "type": "string", "format": "date" },

results in:

`code
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/LocalDate
 at org.jsonschema2pojo.rules.FormatRule.getDateOnlyType(FormatRule.java:135)
 (...)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.LocalDate
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
`

Comment: Okey, the solution of yours is correct. It's just necessary to add joda-time-2.0.jar to buildpath and while compiling to classpath. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

According to the latest jsonschema2pojo docs, for type `Date`, you need to do the following:-

```
{ "type": "string", "format": "date-time" }
```

In the generated POJO, the property will be of type `Date` object

Comment: can someone wish to explain why I got downvoted. my answer is totally correct.
docs are here for anyone's reference
https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Reference